# What is it called when !(a < b) and !(b < a) implies a = b?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I thought it would be some kind of symmetric equality but its impossible to do a google search on this, all I get are definitions of reflexive, symmetric and transitive. I'm not really sure which applies here.

To clarify: this is in a programming context, specifically, I am falling back on two less-than comparisons when equality hasn't been explicitly defined for some type. I'm looking for an accurate name for the function that performs the comparison.

**edit (more details):** < doesn't necessarily imply a real number comparison, (in my case, it would be a floating point anyway, and its almost always a mistake to compare floating point numbers like this).

Actually this problem came up in the context of implementing a generic binary search: I need a comparison operator to perform the search, and then some way to test for equivalence to determine whether my element was actually found.

For things like integers, obviously I can just use equality to know whether or not the element was found. But I also have a case where I search through a set of intervals, and a member-wise equality comparison between two intervals A and B

```
A.start = B.start and A.end = B.end
```

would not yield the result I want. So instead, I define comparison for the Interval type:

```
A < B iff A.start < B.start
```

and then I define equivalence as:

```
not (A < B) and not (B < A)
```

which makes the search do what I want, however my name for the generic version of this comparison function is "reflexively_equal" and I know this isn't right.

Basically my question boils down to this: If you were reading my code, what would I have to name this function in order for you to immediately guess what it does?

Comment: If $a,b$ are in a totally ordered set and $!$ means $\neg$, it's called anti-symmetry.

Comment: I seem to remember it being called trichotomy, but I may have spelled it wrong. Anti-symmetry means (IIRC) that if a<b then not b<a.

Comment: @Ned You're right, it is trichotomy in general (which doesn't invalidate my comment since trichotomy 'is the same' as a totally ordered set). I had missed that. You're wrong about [anti-symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation) though.

Comment: I suppose the assumptions allow for both $a \lt b$ and $b \lt a$ to hold, as far as the Q statement goes.

Comment: Process of elimination?  :)

Comment: hmm... what about "anti-symmetrically equivalent"?

Comment: @GitGud, the first line of the Wiki link you gave says "a relation R on a set X is antisymmetric if there is no pair of distinct elements of X each of which is related by R to the other" which is exactly what I wrote (for the case of an anti-reflexive relation which is virtually always the case when we use the symbol <), and for the reflexive relation obtained by including the diagonal, is equivalent to what you wrote as well.

Comment: @Ned No, what you wrote is $\forall a,b(a<b\implies \neg b<a)$ which isn't at all equivalent to $\forall a,b((a\leq b\land b\leq a)\implies a=b)$, where $a\leq b$ is merely short for $a<b\lor a=b$. In fact the wiki link also states that the correct version of your suggestion is $\forall a,b((a<b\land a\neq b)\implies \neg b<a)$.

Comment: Since the definition for anti-symmetry is $R(a,b) \wedge R(b,a) \implies a = b$ and I decide $R(a,b) \equiv \neg (a < b)$ then could I justifiably call this property "antisymmetric equivalance"?

Comment: @GitGud, I may have been unclear, but I was assuming that the relation < is irreflexive [ i.e. for all a, not (a < a) ], in which case the statements seem to be equivalent. Am I missing something? (I often am)

Comment: @Ned With that assumption, I agree. But it's not a given assumption. Well, everything is cleared up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a and b are asymmetrically equivalent.

*Note: I think this question was misinterpreted in the other answers. GitGud posted "asymmetric" in the comments but not as an answer. After leaving it up for a week I settled on "asymmetrically_equivalent" as a function name. I'd like to credit GitGud instead of myself but it seems this question has gone stale, so I'm self-answering to remove it from the queue.*

Answer (score 3):

It means that $\leq$ is a total relation: any two elements can be compared. To see this, look at the contrapositive: $$a \neq b \implies (a < b) \lor (b < a)$$ Equivalently, the statement is: $$(a = b) \lor (a < b) \lor (b < a)$$

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is just simplifying the expressions:

$\begin{align} \neg (a<b) \text{ and } \neg(b<a) \iff a \geq b \text{ and } b\geq a \iff a = b\end{align}$

This is under the assumption that $a,b$ are real numbers, which I assumed since the notation of the OP indicates use in programming languages.

Comment: There are instances in which $\neg (a<b)$ does not imply $b\leq a$. For instance if $\leq$ means $\subseteq$ it's easy to find examples.

Comment: Have you ever seen using someone $<$ instead of $\subset$? For me it is pretty clear that $<$ and $\leq$ is only used for real numbers and $\subset$ etc is used for sets, and the use of $<$ instead of $\subset$ is just wrong. But I'd be happy if you could tell me where that is the case!

Comment: Yes, I have, any time a person is talking about a Poset in general, and thus might be talking about a poset of sets under inclusion... @flawr

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set

Comment: Ok thank you, I edited the post!

Comment: This answer still doesn't address the question: What is this property called? In general, we name a property when it comes up again and again, and thus the question is about all contexts where it comes up, and the search is for a name, not a restatement of the property in one particular case.